# Sharepoint 2013 publish website migrate

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-migration

I need to create replica server of my SharePoint 2013 publishes multilingual website for disaster recovery. Please suggest me steps to do this.

I installed SharePoint 2013 and SQL server 2012  new server. only one CU  difference is there between new and old SharePoint and I can't apply that SharePoint update to the old server.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

- Build a new farm with the same build number. It make life easy in case of testing and DR.
- Install all required LPs as per the production
- Deploy all customizations as per the Production
- Create new web application, apply all customization(if any)
- Now backup the content db from Old farm and restore it to your New/DR farm
- Attach it to the web application.
- test it.

If your New farm with higher build number than the Production farm, Only sql backup of content db will work.